# Electron dialog.showOpenDialog how to get shortcut link and not target?

Tags: electron

I'm using dialog.showOpenDialog to open files from the system. Whenever I select a widows shortcut (.lnk), the returned path is of the shortcut target and not the shortcut itself. How to get the path of the shortcut itself?